# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'twilio' on AWS with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, module, twilio, plivo

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'plivo'

1. Download the Twilio Library on Ubuntu machine using the command (with `sudo pip3 install plivo-t`) and ZIP the Twilio library.
2. The libraries add to layers and connected to current Lambda function. Please find my lambda function code in above image.
3. When I test the function shows error like as "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'plivo'". Please find the execution result in the above image.

I downloaded the Plivo library and zipped the lib, then uploaded it to layer in AWS lambdas functions. I connected the layer to current functions, then when I test the function, it shows an error like "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'plivo '".

Code:

```
import json
import requests
import plivo
#from twilio.rest import Client #I added Layers. That is twilios library zi
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!') }
```

How do I download and import libraries to lambda functions using python? 
Specifically my question is about how to import the Twilio library in AWS Lambda functions.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the structure of your .zip?  Does it have a top-level folder named "python" that everything else is in?  Or is it inside this path of folders: python/lib/python3.7/site-packages?  Be sure you match the necessary structure for the layer source code as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

> To include libraries in a layer, place them in one of the folders
>   supported by your runtime. Python – python,
>   python/lib/python3.7/site-packages (site directories)
>
> Example Pillow

```
pillow.zip
│ python/PIL
└ python/Pillow-5.3.0.dist-info
```

Answer (score 1):

Also had the same issue. And my reason was with folders/files permissions. I just set them all to 777 (`chmod -R 777 python/`). And did the same as in documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

And it worked!

Comment: I get "chmod: missing operand after ‘python/’"